# Apple Hardware Test doesn't run with original disk

Tags: apple-hardware-test

I have the original disks to my Macbook Pro mid-2010. Holding D or option-D at startup launches internet recovery, which ultimately gives error -3403D in both cases. (I was expecting only option-D to launch internet recovery.) The disk does seem to contain the correct AHT version (it is Mac-F22586C8). How can I run the local, non-internet, disk-based Apple Hardware Test?

Mac OS 10.12.6, 15-inch mid-2010 (MacbookPro6,2), Boot ROM: MBP61.0057.B1C, SMC: 1.58f17

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask what your Mac's EFI Boot ROM and SMC firmware versions are? You can check this by going to Apple > About This Mac. See: [About System Information on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203001). Basically, once you open System Information you'll see your Hardware Overview and the EFI Boot ROM and SMC firmware versions will be listed there. Also, what version of macOS are you running and which model of MBP do you have (i.e. 13", 15" or 17")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a whole range of reasons you're unable to get this to work (e.g. problems with your optical drive; a problem with your disks, etc), so it may be worth downloading AHT directly from Apple and running it from a USB.

1. The version of Apple Hardware Test (AHT) that shipped with your MBP should be AHT 3A171. You can download it directly from Apple [here](http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Hardware_Test/022-4597-A.dmg).
2. Create a bootable USB flash drive by using Disk Utility's Erase function. Make sure you choose OS X Extended for the format and the GUID Partition Map for the scheme.
3. Now have a good read of the *Run AHT from bootable USB stick* section on this github [page](https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest), as this provides the instructions for copying the AHT onto your USB drive and blessing it so it can boot your MBP.

**NOTE:** By following steps 1 and 2 above you have already done the first and third bullet points on the github page.

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Thank you, the USB drive does work. I'm curious as to what you mean by "a whole range of reasons", since the optical drive and CD seem to function totally normally otherwise.

Comment: Other reasons that could account for the problem are firmware/Boot ROM updates that rendered the *original* version of AHT unbootable. However, in your case, if you used the AHT I linked to in my answer, then that **is** the version (or at least it should be) that you have on your CD/DVD, in which case you can eliminate firmware/Boot ROM being a problem in your case. So, that leaves us with most likely an issue with your optical drive and/or disc. You may know your optical drive is fine, but not your disk, unless you can boot another Mac with it? Also, 3rd party hardware can affect things too.